# Find all $n$ such that $\sigma (n)=10$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can someone check my reasoning please.

$10=(2)(5)$

But we know that $\sigma$ is multiplicative, and there is no value $k$ such that $\sigma(k)=2$

So there is no value $n$ such that $\sigma (n)=10$

Comment: What is $\sigma$ ?

Comment: what is $\sigma$?

Comment: sum of divisors

Comment: Guessing it is [the divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function), your reasonning seems fine

Comment: Not following.  $6=2\times 3$ so wouldn't your argument show that $\sigma(n)=6$ is impossible?  But $\sigma(5)=6$.

Comment: To prove the claim you want is a simple matter of checking $n\in \{1,2,\cdots,9\}$.

Comment: But what if n is very large

Comment: Well, just proceed by counting the number of prime divisors.  Your argument would work if we knew that $n=p^aq^b$  To make your argument complete, you have to eliminate $n=p^a$ and more than two factors.

Comment: To be clear, It's not so easy to solve $\sigma(n)=k$ if $k$ is large and has many factorings.    At least, I am not aware of a quick way to handle the general case.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more please? What do you mean eliminate $n=p^a$? Can you give an example?

Comment: Well, your argument works for $n=p^aq^b$ because $\sigma (p^aq^b)=\sigma(p^a)\sigma(p^b)$ and, as you remark, this doesn't work given the only factoring of $10$.  With a little more effort this also eliminates the case of more than $2$ prime factors as well.  However you can't eliminate $n=p^a$ so easily because $\sigma(p^a)$ doesn't have to factor in any particular way.  Of course there is a closed formula for $\sigma(p^a)$ so you could try to solve it that way.

Comment: But you should persuade yourself that your argument is wrong, generally.  for example the equation $\sigma(n)=42$ has a solution even though $42=2\times 3\times 7$ and, as you point out, $\sigma(n)=2$ is impossible.

Comment: But what is it about 10 that lets this method work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47657/discussion-between-derpypenguin-and-lulu).

Comment: Nothing about $10$ makes this method work!  It is not a good method.  Or, rather, it is not a complete method.  The method correctly handles the case of $n=p^aq^b$ which helps.  And, with a little extra thought, also handles three or more prime factors.  But it is incomplete....it does not address the case $n=p^a$.

Answer (score 2):

*$\sigma$ is multiplicative* and *there is no $k$ such that $\sigma(k)=2$* **do not** rule out $\sigma(p^k)=10$.
But since $\sigma(n)\geq n+1$, assuming there is some solution to $\sigma(n)=10$ such a solution has to lie in $[1,9]$, but $\sigma(1)=1,\sigma(2^k)\equiv 1\pmod{2},\sigma(3)=4,\sigma(5)=6,\sigma(6)=12,\sigma(7)=8$ and $\sigma(9)=13$, so there is no solution to $\sigma(n)=10$.